# Can my app access payment methods from Google play?

Tags: android

i am trying to develop an App and need the user pay for a service or good, so i was thinking if there is a way that my App can access the Payments Method stored on the device ?

please if there is a documentation or link that you can bring me where i can start would be great .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just found the documentation, thanks a lot. Here it is if it can help anyone: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/google/play/billing/index.html